# ForEach not working in useEffect using React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, axios

**Context**

- The idea of the project is to have a drop-down menu (an Accordion in Material-UI) of the different Applications.
- To have for each Application its API calls concerning it.
- To have for each API its incoming and outgoing parameters.

I succeeded in having my list of applications and below each one the APIs concerning them but I block to recover for each API their parameters.

The display looks something like this:

> Application n°1
>
> -- APIs 1
>
> -- -- Parameters

Being still learning React in general, I had trouble with the "API" retrieval.

---

**Here is my code:**

```js
export default function documentationv2() {

    // Getteur - Setteur
    const [applis, setApplis] = useState([]);
    const [APIs, setAPIs] = useState({});
    const [parametres, setParametres] = useState({});


    // Chargement
    const loadRessources = () => {
        axios.get('/api/documentation/application')
        .then((response) => {
            setApplis(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }
    
    // Liste des APIs pour une application
    const ListeAPI = (AppliID) => {
        axios.get('/api/documentation/api?app_id=' + AppliID)
        .then((response) => {
            setAPIs(prev => {
                return {
                    ...prev,
                    [AppliID]: response.data
                }
            })
        })
    }

    // Liste des paramètres pour une API
    const ListeParametre = (IdAPI) => {
        console.log('ID : ' + IdAPI)
        axios.get('/api/documentation/parametre?api_id=' + IdAPI)
        .then((response) => {
            setParametres(prev => {
                return {
                    ...prev,
                    [IdAPI]: response.data
                }
            })
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (applis == "" ) {
            loadRessources();
        }
        else{
            console.log('Length Appli : ' + applis.length)
            console.log('Appli : ' + applis.toString())
            applis.length && applis.forEach((application) => ListeAPI(application.IDAPPLI));
        }
    }, [applis])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Length API : ' + APIs.length)
        console.log('API : ' + APIs)
        // APIs.length && 
        APIs.length && Object.values(APIs).forEach((api) => ListeParametre(api.api_id));
    }, [APIs])


    return (
        <Grid container className={classes.root}>
            {/* -- BODY -- */}
            <Grid item className={classes.Body}>
                <Grid container className={classes.GridContainerBody}>
                    {applis.map((application, index) => (
                        <div className={classes.DivContainerBody}>
                            <Grid item className={classes.GridItemLeftBody}>
                                <Accordion key={application.IDAPPLI} className={classes.AccordionBody}>
                                    <AccordionSummary expandIcon={<IconButton className={classes.ButtonBodyShow} disableRipple={true}><ExpandMoreIcon/></IconButton>}>
                                        <Typography>
                                            {application.NOMAPPLI} - ({application.NBAPI})
                                        </Typography>
                                    </AccordionSummary>
                                    <AccordionDetails className={classes.AccordionDetailsApplication}>
                                        {APIs[application.IDAPPLI] && APIs[application.IDAPPLI].map((api, index) => (
                                            <div className={classes.DivDetailsApplication}>
                                                <Accordion key={api.api_id} className={classes.AccordionBody}>
                                                    <AccordionSummary expandIcon={<IconButton className={classes.ButtonBodyShow} disableRipple={true}><ExpandMoreIcon/></IconButton>}>
                                                        <div className={classes.AccordionSumAPI}>
                                                            <Typography>
                                                                {api.api_uri}
                                                            </Typography>
                                                            <Typography>
                                                                {api.api_description}
                                                            </Typography>
                                                            <div className={classes.AccordionSumAPIDiv}>
                                                                <Chip
                                                                    style={{backgroundColor: "#06d6a0", width: "fit-content"}}
                                                                    label={api.api_version}
                                                                />
                                                                <Chip
                                                                    style={{backgroundColor: "#ffd166", width: "fit-content"}}
                                                                    label={api.api_response_type}
                                                                />
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div>
                                                                <Typography>
                                                                    Créé par {api.api_creation_user} le {api.api_date_creation}.
                                                                </Typography>
                                                                <Typography>
                                                                    Modifié par {api.api_maj_user} le {api.api_date_maj}.
                                                                </Typography>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </AccordionSummary>
                                                    <AccordionDetails className={classes.GridContainerBody}>
                                                    {parametres[api.api_id] && parametres[api.api_id].map((parametre, index) => (
                                                        <div key={index}>
                                                            <Typography>
                                                                Paramètre(s) d'entrée :
                                                            </Typography>
                                                            <Divider className={classes.ParamDivider}/>
                                                            <Chip
                                                                style={{backgroundColor: "#06d6a0", width: "fit-content"}}
                                                                label={parametre.INPUT}
                                                            />
                                                            <Typography style={{marginTop: "1%"}}>
                                                                Paramètre(s) de sortie :
                                                            </Typography>
                                                            <Divider className={classes.ParamDivider}/>
                                                            <Chip
                                                                style={{backgroundColor: "#ffd166", width: "fit-content"}}
                                                                label={parametre.OUTPUT}
                                                            />
                                                        </div>
                                                    ))}
                                                    </AccordionDetails>
                                                </Accordion>
                                            </div>
                                        ))}
                                    </AccordionDetails>
                                </Accordion>
                            </Grid>

                            <Grid item className={classes.GridItemRightbody}>
                                <div>
                                    <Tooltip title="Mot de passe" placement="top" arrow>
                                        <IconButton 
                                            className={classes.ButtonHeader}
                                            disableRipple={true}
                                        >
                                            <LockIcon/>
                                        </IconButton>
                                    </Tooltip>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <Tooltip title="Télécharger doc
                                    " placement="top" arrow>
                                        <IconButton 
                                            className={classes.ButtonHeader}
                                            disableRipple={true}
                                        >
                                            <GetAppIcon/>
                                        </IconButton>
                                    </Tooltip>
                                </div>
                            </Grid>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            
        </Grid>
    )
}
```

You can see that I tried to reproduce the same method for the parameters as on the APIs.

I could see that my const "ListeParametre" was not called, with Object.values(APIs) it is called (I understood that API is an object and that I had to convert it to an Array to be able to apply a forEach

```
APIs.length && Object.values(APIs).forEach((api) => ListeParametre(api.api_id));
```

But now no parameters are sent, giving an error with the Axios call

`(console.log('ID : ' + IdAPI)` is undefined)

Note: API.length seems to be undefined

---

**EDIT 1 :**
Inside API via console.log(Oject.entries(APIs))

```
API : [["1", [{"api_id": IdValue, "api_uri": UriValue, "api_description": DescriptionValue, ...}, {...}]]]
```

---

**EDIT 2 :**
When using the Object.entries on API it seems to go the first row of APIs for the first application. But then a 404 error comes in because api_id is undefined.

```
useEffect(() => {
    Object.entries(APIs).length && Object.entries(APIs).forEach((api) => ListeParametre(api.api_id))
}, [APIs])
```

Can someone explain my error? Thanks for any help!
If my problem/title is not clear, tell me please so I can edit it.

Comment: This has very little (if anything) to do with your question but may I suggest to split the code into smaller, more manageable components?

Comment: Yes, it will be more visible. I plan to do that after I  managed to make the page itself.

Comment: Seems like there's an array inside an array in the data. Please share some more data you got from the api. Make sure to rescind any confidential info.

Comment: Since you say `API` is an object, please use Object.entries(API).length instead of API.length

Comment: When using Object.entries(APIs).length, i think it get through the first row of APIs (First application only have 3 APIs). But then api_id is undefined and so I get a 404 error. Updated my post.

Comment: @Quentin please can you add sample data which is being returned by all 3 apis.

Answer (score 0):

In your EDIT1: I saw the object was multiple arrays.

```js
[
    [
        "1",
        [
            {
                "api_id": IdValue,
                "api_uri": UriValue,
                "api_description": DescriptionValue,
                ...
            },
            {...}
         ]
    ]
]
```

I think you can try with this

```js
APIs.length > 0 &&
APIs[0].length > 1 &&
APIs[0][1].length > 0 &&
APIs[0][1].forEach((api) => ListeParametre(api.api_id))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, it doesn't seems to work. It won't even go into ListeParametre. After checking with console.log this is the result : APIs.length > 0 ---> false and APIs[0] is undefined (making a error).

Comment: can you add a code sandbox link for your problem? I think it will be easier to find the solution when seeing the whole component and API response.

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (applis == "" ) {
    loadRessources();
}
else {
    console.log('Length Appli : ' + applis.length)
    console.log('Appli : ' + applis.toString())
    applis.length && applis.forEach(
        (application) => ListeAPI(application.IDAPPLI)
    );
}
```

Sorry, this peace of code doesnt make sense to me, maybe you can provide sandbox example with stubs in API calls?

Here you check if applis is empty string, but you set it by default to array, hence this statement will always be false unless you set applis to string, and only place you ever set applic is loadRessources function

Then in "else" statement you check if applis has length but it will always be empty array as function in which you set applis (loadRessources) is called in that if statement which never gonna be executed

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling `.length` on the object

because you have set the empty state an Object

`const [APIs, setAPIs] = useState({});`

and you are calling `.length` function on a object because it used only on array

I think that's why it never goes true it returns undefined every time

you can use like this:

`Object.entries(API).length && Object.values(APIs).forEach((api) => ListeParametre(api.api_id));`

Answer (score 0):

I think here is the error:

```js
if (applis == "" ) {
    loadRessources();
}
```

Inside `loadRessources` you are calling `setApplis`. You want to call `loadRessources`, `if (applis == "" )` however the way you set the state is this.

```js
const [applis, setApplis] = useState([]);
```

So if statement should be

```js
if (applis === []) {
    loadRessources();
}
```

You are setting APIs inside `ListeAPI` which is called under this condition:

```js
applis.length && applis.forEach(
    (application) => ListeAPI(application.IDAPPLI)
);
```

Since you never called `loadRessources`, `applis` is not set and `ListeAPI` is not called. Since it is not called, `setAPIs` is never set because you are setting it inside `ListeAPI`.

Since APIs are not set `APIs.length` is falsy.